# Memory leak autorelease crash

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

When I try to switch views from A to B, everything works. But when I want to go back from B to A the app crashes?

When I remove the autorelease the app works fine but then it leaks.

Here is the code for switching the views:

```
-(IBAction)switchToExplainView:(id)sender{

explainViewController = [[ExplainViewController alloc]
                         initWithNibName:@"ExplainViewController"
                         bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:explainViewController.view];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider both the controller and the view.

The controller will hold on to its view, but you need to hold on to that controller. If you (auto)release it, it may easily get deallocated, and if you try to access it, your app will crash.

The view itself will be released by it's superview, but not the controller.

One possible solution is to store that controller in an ivar of your class that manages (switches) the views. Only release them when you are done with them.

Comment: do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542143/moving-between-xibs-ios, if you have other examples, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a navigation controller to switch back and forth between views? If yes, you may want to use the `[myNavController pushViewController:... animated:...]` message. After that, you can easily release your `explainViewController`.

Comment: I'm not using a navigationController, I already tried that but I got another error :). I'll try when this doesn't work out. Thx in advance